# Web browser in Java

Tags: java, browser

Is there any browser library for Java, like mechanize for Python?

I want to load sites, parse them, and fill out forms, etc.

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these links:

http://jsoup.org/

http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/

or if you want to use Groovy

http://www.gebish.org/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look on the followings:

1. [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)
2. [prowser](http://prowser.sourceforge.net/)